# how to import CronScheduler using maven dependency

Tags: scala, maven

i am writing a program in scala for scheduled task using cron. here the error i am getting error is:
Failed to execute goal on project corn: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.sample:corn:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: "Could not find artifact com.github.alonsodomin.cron4s:cron4s-jdk8_2.13:jar:0.6.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)" due to maven install failure .
Therefor cannot import "import cron4s.jdk8.scheduler.CronScheduler" and CronScheduler wouldn't work

```scala
import java.time.LocalTime
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
import cron4s.jdk8.scheduler.CronScheduler


object ScheduledTask {
  
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    // Create a scheduled executor service
    val scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1)

    // Define the task to run
    val task = new Runnable {
      def run(): Unit = {
        val now = LocalTime.now()
        if (now.getHour == 14 && now.getMinute == 0) {
          println("Hello, world!")
        }
      }
    }

    // Schedule the task to run at 2 pm every day
    val cronExpr = "0 0 14 * * ?" // Cron expression for 2 pm every day
    val taskFuture = CronScheduler.schedule(cronExpr)(task)(ExecutionContext.global)(scheduler)

    // Shutdown the scheduler after the task has completed
    taskFuture.onComplete(_ => scheduler.shutdown())
  }
}
```

maven Dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.alonsodomin.cron4s</groupId>
    <artifactId>cron4s-core_2.13</artifactId>
    <version>0.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.alonsodomin.cron4s</groupId>
    <artifactId>cron4s-jdk8_2.13</artifactId>
    <version>0.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no such dependency `cron4s-jdk8` (at least on Maven central): https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.alonsodomin.cron4s.

Comment: Is there any other way to import corn?

Comment: Where did you see a reference to this library?